# How to set QoS level 0 for mqtt publish messages in Python Azure IoT Hub Client SDK?

Tags: python, azure, mqtt, azure-iot-hub

I am using [Azure](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdks) custom python SDK to connect to Azure IoT Hub. I am successfully able to connect to the Hub using MQTT but didn't find any way by which one can set QoS level 0 of publishing message. Also, I haven't found any documentation for Python APIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official azure-iot-sdk python library only supports iothub_client. If you want to use the MQTT python SDK, there're at least two ways,

1. Write MQTT library python wrapper for azure-umqtt-c library, it is located in [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-umqtt-c). and has the set QoS level API available. I think it works the same way as azure-iot-sdks python sdk for azure-iot-sdks c class library.
2. If you're using some third-party library, [paho.mqtt](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python) is a good choice. You should be able to connect to the Azure MQTT broker and you also have the set QoS API available.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, also can you tell how to check the current status of connection with Azure IoT Hub using official python SDK? I am using MQTT protocol for the connection.

Answer (score 0):

As addition, you also can use IronPython as Python runtime based on .NET framework, then you can integrate Python with Azure IoTHub SDK for C# if you are familiar with C# more than C, please see the [document](http://ironpython.net/documentation/dotnet/) to know IronPython .NET integration.